# How can only a specific branch be implicitly pulled in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, branch, pull

Running `hg pull` implicitly retrieves everything on the default remote repo, while `hg pull -b Branch-0` explicitly pulls changes only from branch  `Branch-0` from default.

Is there a way to configure/script mercurial to *implicitly* pull only say `Branch-0` from remote if a branch is not specified?

It would be great if the default branch could be specific to a remote path, but I don't find that mandatory.

i.e.

```
$ hg pull remote
# only commits from Branch-0 were pulled
```

Comment: Nope, I don't think there's a way to do this. There's a feature to set a revset that specifies the revisions to *push* by default (see `hg help config.paths`, in particular the discussion about `pushrev`), but not *pull*. Perhaps file a feature request?

Comment: It's public history, why *wouldn't* you want it?

Comment: Because in this case, most branches in the remote repo are the in-progress work of other people. With my local repo, I'd like to quickly pull only the things changed on the main branch and not have the local history continuously polluted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can work with [alias](https://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#alias) in your .hgrc which allows to define new commands. You can use it also to re-define a built-in command like pull - yet that is explicitly warned against in the help files, so use the last line with great care or not at all:

```
[alias]
pullmybranch = pull -b MYBRANCH
pull = pull -b MYBRANCH
```